# Java Eclipse: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error in an imported package

Tags: java, eclipse, package

[image]

As you can see from the above,
Lab1_1.java is under the default package,
Lab1_2.java is under the A package which I created and in which I imported several java files (Eclipse).

When I run a java file in the package A, it gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at A.Lab1_2.main(Lab1_2.java:12)
```

but when I move a file from A to default package and run it, it works fine.

I just want to know why it's not running under the A?

Comment: Can you show Lab1_2?

Comment: At a guess you don't have `package A` at the top of Lab1_2.java - but you need to open the files and look at the errors that Eclipse is reporting.

Comment: What package is being imported? What's on line 12 of `Lab1_2.java`?